# What's the best way to create a single field in the table is designed to keep the computation of a different table fields

Tags: mysql, triggers, view, field

i want to save a balance of user, in the user table .
the balance calculate from other table rows,

is trigger on the other table is the best way ?

or do it in script languages like php ?

It is important that to be accurate, and performance.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in a view, because that way you always know that it is up to date at the time that the data is retrieved.